# Development (Local) with multiple sites using host file and IIS7 - Can't get FCPATH to recognize - Encoded characters

Tags: ee2, global-variables, iis

I am stuck again using IIS7 on a windows server. Trying to replicate the production environment for some testing on a Win7 box using IIS7 and host file to point o the sites.

I have tried using various methods to get a multi-server environment setup, but all have failed. This client in particular wants a development, staging, and production environment. I was looking at using Erik's setup for FocusLab (Thanks Erik!), but for this one in particular, I am trying to implement the one [here](http://jamieonsoftware.com/journal/2011/4/6/getting-to-know-expressionengine-2s-config-file.html).

Even trying to clean up my config file seems to break the site though. I can see the site index page, but the CP is jacked. (See screen)

[image]

Here is the code I have tried:

```
<?php //if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/* ExpressionEngine Configuration
-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
$config['app_version'] = "255";
$config['license_number'] = "MY LICENSE";
$config['debug'] = "1";
$config['install_lock'] = "";
$config['system_folder'] = "MY SYS";
$config['is_system_on'] = "y";
$config['allow_extensions'] = "y";
$config['site_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['server_path'] = FCPATH;
$config['cp_url'] = $config['site_url'] . '/MY SYS/';
$config['theme_folder_url'] = $config['site_url']."/themes/";
$config['theme_folder_path'] = $config['server_path']."/themes/";
$config['save_tmpl_files'] = "y";
$config['tmpl_file_basepath'] = $config['server_path']."/templates/";

/* CodeIgniter Configuration
-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
$config['base_url'] = $config['site_url'];
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$config['language'] = 'english';
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'EE_';
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\\-';
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['directory_trigger'] = 'D';
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'C';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'M';
$config['log_threshold'] = 0;
$config['log_path'] = '';
$config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$config['time_reference'] = 'local';

/* End of file config.php */
/* Location: ./system/expressionengine/config/config.php */
```

Even if I turn off the direct script access denial, I can't display FCPATH. It seems to be an issue with IIS7 and FCPATH.

Any ideas how I can get this going?

*** EDIT ***
I started looking at the paths that EE was trying to use and they are showing this:
    http://bootstrap.com/%3C?=$cp_avatar_path%20?%20$cp_avatar_path%20:%20$cp_theme_url.'images/site_logo.gif'?%3E

%3C is for the '<' character, %20 is space, and %3E is the '>' character.

This is obviously an image being attempted to be rendered.

Is there a reason for the encoded characters showing instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use http://eeinsider.com/articles/multi-server-setup-for-ee-2/ as a basis and work from there?

Comment: taking a look now...

Comment: Thanks for the nudge SG. It ended up being a stupidly overlooked setting of not having short tags on. Crawling through the settings,  I caught it when I was comparing the files though.   Thanks.